# Find prime combinations using Python strings

Tags: python, string, primes

I need to find all the combinations that make a prime number in a string.

Say I had passed in the string 32_23, it would return 3 and 4 since 32323 and 32423 are prime numbers

This is my code so far:

```
def isPrime(n):
 if n < 2:
  return False
 for i in range(2, n):
  if not n % i:
     return False
 return True  

string = input()

for letter in string:
 if letter == "_":
  # Do something here
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you have more than one `_` in your string?

Comment: that's a seriously inefficient isPrime function.

Comment: Also, you can check if something's divisible by three if all the digits added up are divisible by three. *cough*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the blank space against numbers from 0 to 9. Using your code, it will look like this.

```
def isPrime(n):
 if n < 2:
  return False
 for i in range(2, n):
  if not n % i:
     return False
 return True  

string = input()
primes = []

for i in range(10):
    if isPrime(int(string.replace("_", str(i)))):
        primes.append(i)

for num in primes:
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `_` with number from 0-9 and check with `isPrime` function  :

```
def comb_prime(s):
    try:
       for i in range(10):
         n=int(s.replace('_',str(i)))
         if isPrime(n):
             return n
    except:
           print 'enter a valid num'
```